# iPhone Touch View and Sub ImageViews

Tags: iphone, touch, touchesbegan

I have a UIView (mainview), 
including 50 UIImageViews (image1 .. 50))

(all are set to clickable (UIVIEW and also UIImageViews)

Now to test if one of my images is touched I do in 'touchesbegan':

```
touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([touch view] == image1) { NSLog (@"image1 clicked"); }
```

But when i test on if my "mainview" (where all images are in) came clicked
with:

```
if ([touch view] == mainview) { NSLog (@"mainview clicked");}
```

I dont get an confirmation!??

In Short: When mainview alone is clickable i get an OK if clicked
But when I activated all images (in the mainview) to be clickable
.. I just can check if they are clicked but not anymore my mainview.

```
view
   mainview
     image1
     image2
     image3
     ..image50
```

Any ideas?? 
Thx
Chris

Comment: is the touch occurring on one of the image views or on the main view directly?

Comment: on one of the imageviews! Thats the point. But rather checking if each of this 50 Images is touched (with a loop) a simple check if the parent view is touched would be much easier.

Comment: still looking for help! right now i try with:
for( UITouch *touch in [touches allObjects]) 
 {
  if( [touch view] == mainview ) 
  {
   NSLog (@"jojojo");
  }
 }
but still i cant find that my "mainview' is touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because the buttons take the touch. When a touch occurs, it goes up the responder chain  until something responds to it—in this case, your buttons. Check out the [touch section](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW1) of the [Event Handling Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: thx.. i looked in it.. also i dont get the solution .. short sample would be really nice.